# Laravel avoid hard-coding values inside the code

Tags: laravel-5

I am not comfortable with the application making decisions based on hard coded values which might change overtime. For example:

Application makes a decision if a user has access to administration module which has moduleID of 7, then I write the code like:

if(Auth::user()->moduleID == 7){
.....u r administrator..do something here...code....
}

But next time if the somehow the Administration Module ID changes to something else say 4, I don't want to manually search for 7 in all the codes and change to 4.

Is there any best way to avoid hard coding decision statements in laravel...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> administration module which has moduleID of 7

You should not care what the `id` is. Track and lookup records by some other value that you have control over.

Consider adding another column to the table that stores administration modules. Store an identifier in this column that won't change over time.

For your administration record, you could set the identifier to `'admin'`.

For those identifiers that really matter - those you'll use for lookups later, consider setting them as class constants.

```
class Module extends Eloquent
{
    const ADMIN = 'admin';

    // ...
}
```

Now you can compare to `Module::ADMIN` which will never change unless you explicitly alter the constant value defined above. Something like

```
if (Auth::user()->module->identifier === Module::ADMIN) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Will try out your suggestion